# Laravel - Insert JSON Array Data to Database

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have json data coming from mobile end which i need to insert into two tables `orders` and `order_details`

The `orders` table have single entry and the `order_details` table have array of `json object`

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": "1",
    "delivery_boy_id": "3",
    "address_type": "home",
    "address": "Address of the customer",
    "landmark": "Near Address",
    "city": "Mangalore",
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "pincode": "575002",
    "delivery_time_slot": "9am to 11am",
    "delivery_date": "23-7-2017",
    "promo_code_applied": "no",
    "payment_type": "cod",
    "transaction_details": null,
    "total": "580",
    "signature": null,
    "status": "delivered",
    "comment": null,
    "created_at": "2017-06-22 01:05:16",
    "updated_at": "2017-06-22 01:05:16",
    "order_details": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_id": "1",
            "quantity": 2,
            "created_at": "2017-06-22 01:05:16",
            "updated_at": "2017-06-22 01:05:16"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "product_id": "2",
            "quantity": 3,
            "created_at": "2017-06-22 01:05:16",
            "updated_at": "2017-06-22 01:05:16"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to save the data to `orders` table, and i want to modify(append saved order_id) and save the `order_details` data to `order_details` table

```
public function placeOrder(Request $request)
{   
    $order = new Order;

    $order->outlet_id = $request->outlet_id;
    $order->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $order->delivery_boy_id = $request->delivery_boy_id;
    $order->address_type = $request->address_type;
    $order->address = $request->address;
    $order->landmark = $request->landmark;
    $order->city = $request->city;
    $order->state = $request->state;
    $order->pincode = $request->pincode;
    $order->delivery_time_slot = $request->delivery_time_slot;
    $order->delivery_date = $request->delivery_date;
    $order->promo_code_applied = $request->promo_code_applied;
    $order->payment_type = $request->payment_type;
    $order->transaction_details = $request->transaction_details;
    $order->total = $request->total;
    $order->signature = $request->signature;
    $order->status = $request->status;
    $order->comment = $request->comment;
    $order->save();

    //loop through the order_details array from above JSON
    //add the above saved order_id to order_details 
    //save the orers_details array in order_details table

   foreach ($request->order_details as $key => $order_detail) {

        $details = new OrderDetail;

        $details->order_id = $order->id;
        $details->product_id = $order_detail->product_id; //line 43
        $details->quantity = $order_detail->quantity;
        $details->save();

    }

    return Response::json([
        'data' => $order->id
    ]);
}
```

i am getting the following error

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
in OrderController.php (line 43)
```

thank you

Comment: Which line is 43?

Comment: @Alex Howansky  thank you for your time, i have mentioned it in the code  `$details->product_id = $order_detail->product_id; //line 43`

Comment: Ah ok, missed that...

Comment: Have you check that `$order_detail` is an object?

Comment: This works ok for me with the JSON you've posted. I suspect that in your case, you're getting JSON with an empty array for the `order_details` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
 $details->product_id = $order_detail['product_id']
 $details->quantity =$order_detail['quantity'];
```

this happens when you are trying to access normal array values using -> operator.

Comment: thank you so much for your time, really appreciate it, it worked

Comment: i would like to know why using `->operator`  we can't access the value

Comment: @MrRobot Because $order_detail is an array and not an object.